# Adding UIViewController element into xib graphical layout

Tags: ios, forms, layout, uiviewcontroller, xib

I just created a formUnit (viewController) with textField, label, validators and behaviours.
Each unit is an independent field within a form with is own validators and behaviour. 
I want to add these units to a form e.g personal info or signUp.

Is it possible to add a viewController into a xib layout just like a UIButton or UILabel?

Comment: You can't add the ViewController to another ViewController. OfCourse you can add the view of a UIViewController to another ViewController by `[self.view addSubview:anotherViewController.view]`

Comment: In iOS 5 view controller hierarchies were added as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this using a Container View Controller in IB (they are at least available  in storyboards) or programmatically with `addChildViewController:`.